# Setting up Microsoft Entra and Office 365 with AWS domain Hosting, redirection problems when loging in

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, active-directory, system-administration, microsoft-entra-id

This is for a school project, we are simulating a company environment and I'm trying to setup an Active Directory with entra, I bought a custom domain from Namecheap, and Hosted it with AWS. I had been using the Namecheap Private email hosting, but now that I'm trying to setup an AD, I'm having trouble "migrating".

I'm getting a Redirect URI `Redir-Error ArLym14B-IMujPfl2wg`

My custom domain is already verified on the Entra admin page, and it's set to primary. Here's how my routes look on Route53:

[image]

I Added both the txt and mx records thinking It would solve my problem. But this didn't help.
On the Entra Sign in troubleshooting, I see that my users are signing successfully, but still getting no access to outlook I'm able to sign in to azure from these accounts I can't really explain why though.

Extra Info if needed:
[image]
[image]
[image]

I tried messing with the route records a couple times, deleting a creating again the domain, signing in from different devices and browsers, Adding Employee verification on the Entra Admin portal. Waited in case it was setup thing, a little bit over 24hrs now.
None of these things worked.
And I was expecting, to have a regular experience when signing in to my account.